# How to use nextUntil for children elements?

Tags: jquery, addclass, nextuntil

I have a simple table, and I would like to add a class for the cells between the `active` class.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="active">col</td>
    <td>col</td>
    <td>col</td>
    <td>col</td>
    <td>col</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>col</td>
    <td>col</td>
    <td>col</td>
    <td class="active">col</td>
    <td>col</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that the second `active` col is in a new `tr`. How can I achieve the expected functionality?

Comment: **Disclaimer: I wrote this plugin** - You can use my nextInDOM plugin with a simple while loop to achieve this - Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xxg48zfy/ (The red ones are `.active`, the blue ones are the ones on whom the new class was added)

Comment: You're welcome. :) Please don't link to the script directly as done in the fiddle - as it is from a production site of mine. Please copy the code in the JS file and serve from your own server. Thanks.